# Ignore Path and Extension in OllyDBG 2?

Tags: ollydbg, debuggers, breakpoint

I have an exe on my desktop that i began debugging a while ago, so i have a lot of notes/breakpoints stored in the udd file. I now need to move that exe to a different directory but Olly sees it as a new exe because of the change in directory, so it creates a new udd file.

After a bunch of searching i see that Olly v1 has an option "Debugging options -> Security -> Ignore path and extension" but i don't see this in Olly v2. Per http://ollydbg.de/version2.html, the ability to do this has been present since OllyDbg 2.01 alpha 3:

- Option to load .udd information even when path, file name or file checksum is different.

does anyone know how to do this?